# Which is an appropriate way to present the addition, edit and deletion of something in a use case diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

For example, if you have an eShop, what would you do as far as the basket is concerned since you can add / edit / delete products from it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends and you can discuss with anyone. What I usually do is to name the UC `CRUD <something>` or I apply a stereotype `<<crud>>`. In cases where you have a r/o access I place two bubbles, one for the CRUD and one for the r/o which `<<extends>>` the CRUD. There is no common rule. YMMV